# How to create an automatic news site?

Tags: parsing, rss, feed

I've seen sites like this (http://www.tradename.net/) on the web that seem to be nothing more than a collection of news articles pulled in from different places - all seemingly automated... I would like to know how can I create something like this that:
(a) either automatically, one its own pulls data from different news feeds and creates these articles/news-conent, OR
(b) I run a program periodically to update all its content

I am looking for a ready-to-run software / module that I can take and put in either the keywords or links to news feeds and get it to work... I'm not interested in one of those paid template sites.

Another example: http://www.limitedliability.org/

Comment: You need to be a bit more specific about what you DO know how to do.

Comment: lol - alrighty - I do have accounts on webhosts - thats not a problem. I DO know php, but dont mind picking up other things as requried. I am looking for things that basically work but dont need a headache to get working...

Comment: And again: Then go for php...
It's very very easy to parse rss-feeds using php. There are LOADS of docs around.

Comment: Thanks Younes - but thats just part of it - i get all this data, but WHERE do i place it on the site? I am looking for a template or some s/w module that arranges things properly. Do you get what I mean?

Comment: did you go ahead with this idea?

Answer (score 1):

You can just make your own website like that. Just use rss-feeds from topics / newswebsites that you like to show your users. Customize your website like how you want it yourself using one of the scripting languages. It's not very hard to loop through all news flashes in a rss-feed and show them to your users.

You can use [PHP](http://www.softarea51.com/tutorials/parse_rss_with_php.html)

Or [.NET](http://rollerweblogger.org/roller/entry/parsing_rss_with_net)

Or [Javascript](http://www.captain.at/howto-ajax-parse-rss.php)

Ans obviously there are more ways to do this. Just take a good look around and check with what scripting language you feel most comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

Create a script that parses the rss-feeds from the news sites, and only store the ones that you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

Or just create your own Google News feed and add it to your site. There are free feeds for non-commercial use.

- [Available Google News Feeds](http://www.google.com/support/news/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=59255)
- [RSS Feeds: Incorporate feeds onto my site](http://www.google.com/support/news/bin/answer.py?answer=40796)

Comment: This is interesting, but it looks like these rss feeds dont "appear" on the site itself...